# C# List<T> get return a sorted list

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0

What I have is basically:

```
public class Object{
    public bool IsObjectValid { set; get; }
}

public class MyThing{
    public List<Object> Objects { set; get; }
}
```

What I want to do:

```
public class ObjectsFiltered{
    public List<Object> ValidObjects{
        get{
            var list = LFs.Sort<_LF> where (IsObjectValid == true);
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

I know there has to be a way to sort out the List, filtering out the bool true/false. I just can't seem to wrap my head around Linq fully. I just can't seem to find a tutorial that screams "AH HA!" about Linq  Lambda to me :/

I'd rather just return a subset, only only keep one "object" alive... instead of my current setup of multiple sets of lists. KISS.

Ultimately I will use the bool-toggles to feed TreeViews on my WPF form(s).

Clarification: I think the goal is to have a one list (List Objects) and a couple properties that show a filtered version of Objects. Instead of having Objects, ObjecstValid, ObjectsInvalid, ObjectsSomeOtherRuleSet... each a different List...

I'd like to have One List to rule them all... and have properties that return a variation on the list, as desired.

Comment: I think your question isn't very clear. What do you mean by "sort out" and "filtering out the bool true/false"?

Comment: As in... I have the original List<Object> Objects. I want to have a property that outputs Objects.IsObjectValid == true. Inside the IsValid bool is logic that determines if the object is properly setup. If it's true, show up in secondary List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<Object> ValidObjects{ 
    get{ 
        return LFs.Where(item => item.IsObjectValid)
                  .OrderBy(item => item.SomeProperty); 
    } 
}
```

Unless you *need* a `List<T>`, it's better to return an `IEnumerable<T>`, so that you won't store it all in-memory.

The lambda expression `item => item.SomeProperty` is an inline function that takes a parameter called `item` and returns `item.SomeProperty`.  (The parameter and return types are inferred by the compiler)

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. I've seen similar setups on other questions here, just so hard putting pieces together. Once I figure out why XAML is now yelling at me, I'll report back.

Comment: Note that `Sort()` and `OrderBy()` might have different outcomes due to different algorithms used underneath

Answer (score 0):

To filter your objects, you can return simply:

```
return LFs.Where(x => x.IsObjectValid).ToList();
```

Note, however, that if you intend to draw on that function frequently, you may see some performance boost by maintaining a pre-filtered list internally.

Answer (score -2):

```
 LFs.Where(x => x.IsObjectValid).ToList().Sort()
```

To sort useing default compared. Otherwise

```
 LFs.Where(x => x.IsObjectValid).OrderBy(x => x.PropertyToSortBy).ToList();
```